# Short circuiting in place of ternary operator

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

Try to learn short circuiting and doing some assignments . Have the following code

```
game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2 && `${game.team1} is more likely to win` || `${game.team2} is more likely to win`
```

My understanding was that && operator treats left-side as 1 part of expression and whole right side as a 2nd part. So I don't quite understand why this returns `{game.team2}....` in the end.

Could you help me clarify this please?

P.S. Just to be more precise, the code above works well and does what it has to do, but I struggle to understand how exactly it works and why it works this way.

Comment: note that using string templates means you are using truthy values, because it's strings regardless what you assign to the variable inside it

Comment: Yes, I understand it. That's what I need. Actually I was asked to replace if/else with expression that is not a ternary operator related

Comment: please add the problem, you have with this code.

Comment: Let's write it out in normal syntax: `if (game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2) { "$game.team1}" } else { "$game.team2" }`. It's just an odd syntax to achieve the same.

Comment: then you can use the `switch` statement

Comment: @RecencyEffect yep, it is, but it is what the teacher asks to do.

Comment: @NinaScholz no problem with this code, it works perfectly, I produced it myself but I struggle to fully understand WHY it works

Comment: Alright now I get what you were looking for, in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: the previous solution has been removed according to your question*

As you only need to understand how short-circuit evaluation of logical operator works, so I will add the following explanation:

**I -   Keypoints:**

1- logical AND operator `&&` returns the first falsy value, and if all operands were evaluated, it returns the last one.

2- logical OR operator `||` returns the first truthy value, and if all operands were evaluated, it returns the last one.

3- The precedence of AND `&&` operator is higher than OR `||`

4- Check the [table list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) of JS operators precedence

In your example, both operands (arguments) of the logical OR are truth (strings).

**II - Example:**

Starting from your code, let's consider this object of values:

```js
const game = {
    odds: {
        team1: 10,
        team2: 3
    }
}

const winner = game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2 && `$team1 is more likely to win` || `team2 is more likely to win`
console.log(winner)
```

Here, `winner` will be assigned to the last operand. But why? Let's break-down the logic (remember the keypoints):

1- `game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2` is `false` and `$team1 is more likely to win` is truthy as it's a string, then `&&` will return the first falsy value.

2- `game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2` is returned (still false). and it's evaluated now with `team2 is more likely to win` which is a truthy string.

3- the logical OR return the first truthy value, therefore `team2 is more likely to win` is assigned to `winner`.

I hope it's clear now

Comment: Yes, it's clear now, I just treated operator precedence wrong, hence my doubts. Thank you for clarification

Comment: When in doubt about precedence, use parens :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem of this code is to have three parts which can change the result.

```
a < b && c || d
^^^^^    ^    ^
```

This answer takes the terms [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) especially for part `c` and `d`.

If the first condition `a < b` is `true`, it takes `c` as long as `c` is truthy. If not, it takes `d`.

If the first condition is `false`, it takes `d`, because of the short circuit `&&`.

For having a better understanding, here a table of truth. (`-` means value does not matter):

| `a < b` | `c` | `d` | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `true` | truthy | - | `c` |
| `true` | falsy | `d` | `d` |
| `false` | - | `d` | `d` |

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding was that && operator treats left-side as 1 part of expression and whole right side as a 2nd part

No, it doesn't. The `&&` has a [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the `||`. It's parsed as

```
((game.odds.team1 < game.odds.team2) && `${game.team1} is more likely to win`) || `${game.team2} is more likely to win`
```

But yeah, while it's a nice exercise you definitely should use the `?:` conditional operator for this :-) Apart from expressiveness, another reason is that `c ? t : e` is not always equal to `c && t || e`. Can you figure out for which values of `t` that might be?

Comment: Probably if t is also a falsy value? Not sure though

Comment: @vdmclcv Precisely!